# How to add CakePHP LDAP Authentication?

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, ldap

I am very new to CakePHP and this is my first attempt using LDAP .
I get the following error message using [this CakePHP Ldap Authentication](http://www.analogrithems.com/rant/2012/01/03/cakephp-2-0-ldapauth/) example.

> LDAP not configured on this server. The PHP-LDAP extension is probably
>   missing!

My database.php code is

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => 'my!password',
        'database' => 'my_db',
        'prefix' => '',
        //'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );      
    public $ldap = array(
        'datasource' => 'Idbroker.LdapSource',
        'host' => 'dc1.my_domain.net',
        'port' => 3268,
        'basedn' => 'CN=Users,DC=my_domain,DC=net',
        'login' => 'CN=theadmin,DC=my_domain,DC=net',
        'password' => 'my!password',
        'database' => '',
        'tls'         => false,
        'type' => 'ActiveDirectory',
        'version' => 3,
    );
}
```

The platform is Windows Server 2012 | Apache HTTP | CollabNet | Subversion | Microsoft Active Directory.
Modules util_ldap mod_authnz_ldap *are* loaded on the apache2handler according to phpinfo.php and the php.ini on the server contains

```
extension=php_ldap.dll
[ldap]
; -1 for unlimited.
ldap.max_links = -1
```

Is there something else that needs to be loaded on the server for php-ldap?
Are there additional CakePHP debug methods I should be using?

Comment: What OS is this running on?

Comment: use same config same as $ldap in $default,just for tesing purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For php-ldap to work in Win32 environments, you need to have the files `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` in your system path. Depending on your PHP version, you may also need `libsasl.dll`.

Check to see if those are accessible on your system. Also, make sure `php-ldap.dll` is really available. At least [that's how i got it to work on my Windows system](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php).